# AWS Elasticbeanstalk and ALB with web socket

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, websocket, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-application-load-balancer

I have just migrated an application to ELB using Application Load Balancer. My app uses a web socket, and seems not to work due to the load balancer. For what I've seen, ALB does not support web sockets. (only http and https) Is there any option to make them work?.
I tried adding a listener to the port that the websocket is listening (8001) and opening the port in the security group but still not working.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: ALBs do support websockets natively - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-listeners.html#listener-configuration

Comment: Check this post out - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58793966/node-js-server-with-websockets-on-elastic-beanstalk-alb-without-socket-io

Comment: Thanks, I'm missing adding the process with stickiness enabled. Regarding the security group port is already open to all. I will try with that..good to know that eb alb supports websocket though

Comment: Still not working..Im getting this error "Invalid status code. Expected 101, received: 404"

Comment: So sounds like the handshake is failing - maybe this might help https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-websockets-and-load-balancers-part-two/

Answer (score 1):

We had the same issue and took us hours and hours to figure it out! Turns out you need to set the ELB protocol to either `SSL` instead of `HTTPS` or `TCP` instead of `HTTP`